# How to import contact from gmail using java

Tags: java, gmail

Hi I am new to java web. I want to import my contacts from gmail. I donot know how to do it. How to import contacts from gmail.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the API as given here http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#Retrieving

Comment: Note that at the top of the page it says that this is an old version, you should use this instead: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html

Answer (score 6):

socialauth is a java library that allows importing contacts from Google, Yahoo or Hotmail.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/