# How to import our contact list from Gmail through a Java program

Tags: java, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import contact from gmail using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109851/how-to-import-contact-from-gmail-using-java)

I want to import my contact list on gmail through a Java program.

Comment: accept some answers to your old questions please

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109851/how-to-import-contact-from-gmail-using-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at :
http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/contacts/

and :
http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html